# How to enable async/await with babel with support for IE11

Tags: javascript, async-await, internet-explorer-11, babeljs

I am hoping to use async/await in my source code and have it transpiled by babel to something useable by `>0.25% not dead`.

My head is spinning with the plethora of ways to attack this. Some are deprecated, some flat out don't work, and the one that I have gotten to work more than doubles the size of my library.

I've tried using `@babel/polyfill` with `@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator` and it works well, but the library goes from ~500kB to ~1.1MB.

I also tried leaving it to `@babel/preset-env` by giving it `>0.25% not dead`, but that hasn't made a difference. I get:

> regeneratorRuntime is undefined

I'm hoping there is a better way to do this than including all this `regeneratorRuntime` stuff...

I'd rather go back to the callback pyramid of doom than ship a library over 1mb...

I am using:

- webpack 4.41.0
- babel 7.6.2

Comment: Yeah, usually you don't want to use babel to transpile your library code. You'll possibly want polyfills, but you don't want to rely on transpilation in a library.

Comment: For your `@babel/preset-env` what is your `useBuiltIns` set it? Try setting it to `entry` and see if that helps.

Comment: @user1538301 not sure what you mean. How would I get async await working with a polyfill?

Comment: @MatthewGoulart You wouldn't, you just wouldn't use it. You can get `Promises` with a polyfill, which IMO I prefer to `async/await` (I don't like how `async/await` changes return types.. I like to know exactly what I'm looking at)

Comment: @user1538301Interesting... Can you elaborate a bit as to why you wouldn't? What are the disadvantages to using babel? In what circumstances *would* one use babel?

Comment: @user1538301 Also, i'm not sure what you mean by "changes the return type". An async function returns a `Promise` and you can either `await` that promise or, well, do whatever you want with it...

Comment: @MatthewGoulart that's exactly what I mean haha, though that's purely a matter of opinion. In practice it is exactly the same as working with `Promise`s just more concise

Comment: @user1538301Haha I get it. I am a C# programmer by trade so async/await tickles my fancy. Any thoughts on the comment right before my last one? You've scared me into thinking I made a mistake by using babel...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only need the generator polyfill — which is needed for async/await — then you can just use [facebook/regenerator](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator).

> You could follow the steps to support async/await in IE 11:
>
> - use [babel-preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env)
> - `yarn add regenerator` or `npm install regenerator`
> - add `node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (10.7kb minified)` into your bundle

Reference link: [Add ES7 Async/Await Support for your Webapp in 3 Easy Steps](https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002)

Comment: Good compromise between size added to bundle and use of new features. Especially considering the pure joy of async/await. Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick question regarding the steps. I've installed regenerator but what does add node_modules/regenerator... into your bundle.  Mean?

Comment: how do you add node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js (10.7kb minified) into your bundle? I'm confused what it means to add something to my bundle

Comment: @user3717206 I think that's mean you just need to add `node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js` this file into the project you need.

Comment: That webpack thing didn't work for me, but this article did it https://dev.to/btandayamo/a-guide-to-through-async-await-with-babel-and-webpack-mh5