# Upgrading Babel from 6 to 7 breaks test stubs

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm upgrading Babel from 6.26.0 to 7.8.3 and some of my tests are now breaking. It appears that the new version is preventing an exported function from being stubbed by Sinon after the upgrade.

Is there a configuration setting or plugin that I need to use as part of the upgrade to get the older behavior?

Here is an example of a test that is breaking:

```
it('a calls b', function () {
  bStub = sinon.stub(B, 'default');
  a.do();
  expect(bStub.calledOnce).to.be.true; // this used to be true but no is now false
});
```

The functions are mostly simple but I added some logging code and it appears that B() used to stub as expected when using the older version of Babel but it no longer gets stubbed successfully and the actual B() function is called.

The actual function under test:
A.js

```
A.do = function () {
  return B();
};

export default A;
```

And the function call that is being stubbed out:
B.js

```
export default function B () {
  ...
};
```

Some config changes I made as part of the upgrade:

project.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
+    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
+    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
+    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
-    "babel-cli": "^6.5.1",
-    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
-    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
-    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
+    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
  ...
}
```

.babelrc

```
 {
-  "presets": ["es2015"]
+  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
 }
```

webpack.config.json

```
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       test: /\.js$/,
       exclude: /node_modules|scripts|dist|build\//,
       use: {
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options: {
-            presets: ['es2015']
+            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
         }
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make this work again by adding an additional `modules` configuration setting to the babel-loader. My tests now pass as expected.

I was able to get the tests to pass using the `umd` and `commonjs` values but I ended up going with `commonjs` because that is the most compatible with the default from the previous version (as far as I could tell).

webpack.config.js

```
{
...
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { "modules": "commonjs" }]]
          }
        }
...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Any updates? Exactly the same situation here. Could anyone throw light on this?

Except that I had to do the following in addition - 
install regenerator & core-js@3.  As in [Link](https://medium.com/@zwacky/add-es7-async-await-support-into-your-non-bleeding-edge-build-process-ad0dded0d002)

For the issue - regeneratorRuntime is not defined [Link](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8829)

Have tried both these methods - 
[Link1](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-runtime.html)

> you can directly import "core-js" or use @babel/preset-env's useBuiltIns option.

[Link2](http://directly%20including%20core-js/stable%20(to%20polyfill%20ECMAScript%20features)%20and%20regenerator-runtime/runtime)

> in favor of directly including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime

Have referred to [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558916/babel-7-referenceerror-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33527653/babel-6-regeneratorruntime-is-not-defined#33527883), [Ref3](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/934), [Ref4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773129/how-to-enable-async-await-with-babel-with-support-for-ie11).

Finally, it seems that sinon stub behavior are not recognized -

> TypeError: _common__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.functionName.withArgs
>   is not a function

When debugging the stub behavior is not captured in the tests.

Comment: The answer has the solution I found, I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: the answer above works perfect! In addition the following webpack config was used in normal build (other than test/coverage) `{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
              presets: [
                [
                  "@babel/preset-env",
                  {
                    useBuiltIns: "usage",
                    corejs: { version: 3, proposals: false },
                    modules: "umd"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }`