# Async Javascript Function not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, async-await

The code below works in chrome, however when I run it in IE 11 I get a "SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'" error.  Is this possible to accomplish in IE?

Code:

```
    fileInput.addEventListener('change', async function (evnt) {

        for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; i++) {
            var fileId = 'file' + fileCount.toString();

            const base64String = await fileToBase64(fileInput.files[i]);

            fileList.push(
                {
                    filename: fileInput.files[i].name,
                    fileSize: fileInput.files[i].size,
                    base64: base64String,
                    tableId: tableId,
                    fileId: fileId,
                    documentType: "null",
                    extension: fileInput.files[i].name.split('.')[1]
                });
            fileCount++;
            addToTable(fileList[fileList.length - 1])
        }
    }, false);
```

Comment: [You need a polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773129/how-to-enable-async-await-with-babel-with-support-for-ie11)

Comment: [Async function are not supported in IE 11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions).

Comment: Are you working for a bank which needs to support ie11?

Comment: Insurance... Many of our agents still use IE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE does not support `async` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Browser_compatibility

If you compile with something like `babel` then it can fake it for you.